# How to detect if a Node.js script is running through a shell pipe?

Tags: bash, node.js, pipe

My question is similar to this one: [How to detect if my shell script is running through a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/detect-if-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe). The difference is that the shell script I’m working on is written in Node.js.

Let’s say I enter:

```
echo "foo bar" | ./test.js
```

Then how can I get the value `"foo bar"` in `test.js`?

I’ve read [Unix and Node: Pipes and Streams](http://dailyjs.com/2012/03/08/unix-node-pipes/) but that only seems to offer an asynchronous solution (unless I’m mistaken). I’m looking for a synchronous solution. Also, with this technique, it doesn’t seem very straightforward to detect if the script is being piped or not.

TL;DR My question is two-fold:

1. How to detect if a Node.js script is running through a shell pipe, e.g. `echo "foo bar" | ./test.js`?
2. If so, how to read out the piped value in Node.js?

Comment: Collateral note: in case you can not touch the original script and you still want to obtain a similar result of pipe try: `./test.js $(echo 'foo bar')`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pipes are made to handle small inputs like "foo bar" but also huge files.

The stream API makes sure that you can start handling data without waiting for the huge file to be totally piped through (this is better for speed & memory). The way it does this is by giving you chunks of data.

There is no synchronous API for pipes. If you really want to have the whole piped input in your hands before doing something, you can use

**note: use only [node >= 0.10.0](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/03/11/node-v0-10-0-stable/) because the example uses the stream2 API**

```
var data = '';
function withPipe(data) {
   console.log('content was piped');
   console.log(data.trim());
}
function withoutPipe() {
   console.log('no content was piped');
}

var self = process.stdin;
self.on('readable', function() {
    var chunk = this.read();
    if (chunk === null) {
        withoutPipe();
    } else {
       data += chunk;
    }
});
self.on('end', function() {
   withPipe(data);
});
```

test with

```
echo "foo bar" | node test.js
```

and

```
node test.js
```

Comment: `node test.js` hangs for me in `v10.16.0`

Answer (score 51):

I just found out a simpler answer to part of my question.

To quickly and synchronously detect if piped content is being passed to the current script in Node.js, use the `process.stdin.isTTY` boolean:

```
$ node -p -e 'process.stdin.isTTY'
true
$ echo 'foo' | node -p -e 'process.stdin.isTTY'
undefined
```

So, in a script, you could do something like this:

```
if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
  // handle shell arguments
} else {
  // handle piped content (see Jerome’s answer)
}
```

The reason I didn’t find this before is because I was looking at the documentation for `process`, where `isTTY` is not mentioned at all. Instead, it’s mentioned in [the TTY documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/tty.html).

Comment: unfortunately, this will fail in a child process: `node -p -e "require('child_process').exec(\"node -p -e 'process.stdin.isTTY'\", (err, res) => console.log('err:', err, 'res:', res))"`

Comment: TTY may be unavailable in some situations (e.g. Docker container launched without pseudo-tty) and checking `process.stdin.isTTY` will fail.

Comment: Damn. Is there anything we we can do about this? Seems like a fairly simple problem for unix programs.

Comment: @Lacek in what way does it fail? Is `process.stdin === undefined` or something? @maxlath that works for me on Node 14

Comment: @CameronTacklind `docker run -t --rm node node -pe 'process.stdin.isTTY'` returns `true` while `docker run --rm node node -pe 'process.stdin.isTTY'` returns `undefined`. So the execution environment also affects `process.stdin.isTTY`. It being `undefined` does not always mean node process is piped.

Answer (score 14):

It turns out that `process.stdin.isTTY` is not reliable because you can spawn a child process that is not a TTY.

I found a better solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382849/determine-if-process-is-connected-to-another-process-via-pipes) using [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

You can test to see if your program with piped in or out with these functions:

```
function pipedIn(cb) {
    fs.fstat(0, function(err, stats) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err)
        } else {
            cb(null, stats.isFIFO())
        }
    })
}

function pipedOut(cb) {
    fs.fstat(1, function(err, stats) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err)
        } else {
            cb(null, stats.isFIFO())
        }
    })
}

pipedIn((err, x) => console.log("in", x))
pipedOut((err, x) => console.log("out", x))
```

Here's some tests demonstrating that it works.

```
❯❯❯ node pipes.js
in false
out false
❯❯❯ node pipes.js | cat -
in false
out true
❯❯❯ echo 'hello' | node pipes.js | cat -
in true
out true
❯❯❯ echo 'hello' | node pipes.js
in true
out false
❯❯❯ node -p -e "let x = require('child_process').exec(\"node pipes.js\", (err, res) => console.log(res))"
undefined
in false
out false
❯❯❯ node -p -e "let x = require('child_process').exec(\"echo 'hello' | node pipes.js\", (err, res) => console.log(res))"
undefined
in true
out false
❯❯❯ node -p -e "let x = require('child_process').exec(\"echo 'hello' | node pipes.js | cat -\", (err, res) => console.log(res))"
undefined
in true
out true
❯❯❯ node -p -e "let x = require('child_process').exec(\"node pipes.js | cat -\", (err, res) => console.log(res))"
undefined
in false
out true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pipe into nodejs using an **inline --eval** string in bash, `cat` works too:

```
$ echo "Hello" | node -e "console.log(process.argv[1]+' pipe');" "$(cat)"
# "Hello pipe"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `stdout` (not `stdin` like suggested elsewhere) like this:

```
if (process.stdout.isTTY) {
  // not piped
} else {
  // piped
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be the reverse? i.e. `node foo.js | cat`