# Clojure: how to tell if out is going to console or is being piped?

Tags: clojure, command-line-interface

I'm writing a clojure cli and would like to know if there is a way to test if the *out* (i.e. println) is being written to a console or is being piped to another program?

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/how-to-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe) question but for clojure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clojure is hosted language, so system interaction related stuff is more or less equivalent to Java. For Java there exists only partial solution described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23419451/4430998). You can of course implement `isatty()` using JNI and then interop from Clojure.

However, from ClojureScript hosted on Node.js it's easily achievable using `process.stdin.isTTY` (in ClojureScript would be `(-> process .-stdin .-isTTY)`). More details are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15485424/4430998).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(-> process .-stdin .-isTTY)`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [jnr-posix](http://libraries.io/maven/com.github.jnr:jnr-posix) Java library

```
[com.github.jnr/jnr-posix "3.0.10"]
```

to call native posix methods directly from Clojure (using Java Interop):

```clj
(import 'jnr.posix.POSIXFactory)

(def posix (POSIXFactory/getPOSIX))
(.isatty posix java.io.FileDescriptor/out)
```

**N.B.** If you'll run you Clojure application using `lein run` command, Clojure will not be able to identify TTY terminal since `lein` will internally pipe `stdio` between two java processes. You could avoid internal piping by using `lein trampoline run` command or compiled jar file.